# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"

Tags: three.js, webgl, gltf

I am having a really hard time understanding why my program is crashing due to this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I am trying to make my html file communicate with the serial.js file that I created. The html is simply in the project folder, but the serial.js file is being stored in a js folder that I have for the project (needed to import some object loader templates downloaded from the three.js website.)

This is what I've tried so far in my html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Three.js Crash Course</title>
   <style>
   body
   { 
     margin: 0; 
   }
   canvas
   {
     width: 100%; height: 100%;
   } 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <script src = "js/three.js"></script>
 <script src = "js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
 <script type = "module" src = "./js/serial.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried it with just "/js/serial"..ect and "../js/serial.js". Why is it not recognizing and running the file?

I've also included an image if it's helpful for understanding the way I've set up my file structure.
[image: file structure]

Answer (score 2):

You are importing ES6 modules like global scripts which is not valid. I suggest you use the files from the [examples/js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js) or by using proper module syntax.

```js
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.3/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="module">

    import * as THREE from 'three';

    import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.3/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

Comment: The OP wants to use his locally downloaded three and orbit control javascript files the 'old way', probably without even creating a local server, just like I do, so I'm not sure how useful is this answer in that case. Forcing people to use online sources, ES6 standards and dozens of other requirements or dependencies, while it may be suitable in an online context, only complicates and restricts free offline usage, testing and debugging of similar scripts. Security concerns hysteria shouldn't prevent unobstructed development in cases where such threats usually don't exist.

Comment: @YinCognyto this answer is exactly the solution I was looking for

Comment: @Bigboss01 Well, not really a solution, more of a reaction to how things stand nowadays. I get the reasons and the fact the Three.js developers are just following the overall trend and try to keep their library up to date, but it's not pretty. As for a proper solution, getting Node.js, doing `npm install -g http-server` to install the local server globally, bypassing CORS on `http://localhost:8080/` via `http-server -a localhost -p 8080 -c-1 --cors`, using paths like `http://localhost:8080/[filenamehere]` and adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to other resources is one way of doing it locally.

Comment: @YinCognyto my specific use case was embedding threejs on webflow which doesn't allow for that level of flexibility. Webflow is a subpar alternative but its what the job required- I agree that things should be done/made better. Thanks for the extra information by the way, might be useful!

Comment: @Bigboss01 No problem. Yeah, WYSIWYG page builders (if I correctly understood what WebFlow aims to be) are not that flexible as the "manual" design of web pages. I used to use such tools myself some time ago, and while they simplify the work to some extent, there is a trade off in other parts of the workflow. Hopefully you will find a way to get things done with the least hassle possible. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the GLTFLoader.js or any other file encountering the same error. Find the import statement for "three" and replace "three" with the complete file path first. If you encounter a new error related to permissions or similar, navigate to the corresponding folder from the path of GLTFLoader.js. If you need to navigate to a path that involves moving backward, you can use "../" to move back. For example, "../../../build/three.module.js".

exemple:
import {
BufferGeometry,
FileLoader,
Float32BufferAttribute,
Group,
LineBasicMaterial,
LineSegments,
Loader,
Material,
Mesh,
MeshPhongMaterial,
Points,
PointsMaterial,
Vector3,
Color
} from 'three';
replace to
import {
BufferGeometry,
FileLoader,
Float32BufferAttribute,
Group,
LineBasicMaterial,
LineSegments,
Loader,
Material,
Mesh,
MeshPhongMaterial,
Points,
PointsMaterial,
Vector3,
Color
} from '../../../build/three.module.js';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).