# ThreeJS not loading in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, three.js, threejs-editor

I'm using ThreeJS to present 3D files online. It works like a charm on Chrome and MS Edge, but on Firefox I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “three”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

In GTFLLoader.js:64:7

My code looks like this:

```
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.141/build/three.module.js';
import {
    GLTFLoader
} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.141/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import {
    OrbitControls
} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.142/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {
    RoomEnvironment
} from "/wp-content/plugins/lc-plugin/public/js/libs/RoomEnvironment.js";
[...]
```

I've read in this thread: [Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562668/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-three-examples-jsm-loade)

Advice to add importmap. I've added this:

```
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "three": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.141/build/three.module.js"
    }
}
```

But nothing changed. How to fix this? I've tried inspecting the code of the GTFLoader.js, but the problem looks like it lies in this file itself. Is the ThreeJS not compatibile with Firefox?

Comment: Are you loading the JS file before all that? You can't do the module import directly... Check the documentation https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Comment: No, this is the only loading I'm doing. Should I extract all the links and add them to the importmap?

Comment: I've added it to the importmap, 3D started to work but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND SOLUTION! Speed___ Problem is with text structure, example how to fix it:

CORRECT:

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "./includes/threejs/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "./includes/threejs/addons/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script>
```

ERROR:

```
<script type="importmap">

    {
        "imports": 
        {
            "three":            "./includes/threejs/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/":    "./includes/threejs/addons/jsm/"
        }
    }

</script>
```

Working example here: http://rawjet.com/demos/threejs-webgl-product-water/